# Wildfly 8 : Separate thread pool for different applications

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8

In Wildfly 8, I have multiple applications deployed. For one of the applications, I want to assign a separate thread pool (and control number of threads). The idea here is if for some reason, this particular application is stuck (consuming all the available threads), other applications will NOT be impacted because of that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add jboss-web.xml to your apps WEB-INF
with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
  <executor-name>my-app-worker</executor-name>
</jboss-web>
```

And define worker with that name in IO subsystem.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
    ...
    <worker name="my-app-worker" ... />
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: I have not got an opportunity to validate yet. Once validated I will accept it.